# Backbone listen to collection, find out which model has changed

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view which listens to changes in a collection - if the collection changes then the view is rendered once again.

```
this.listenTo(someCollection, "change", this.someMethod);
```

I'd like to know what exactly has changed inside the collection, how can I find out what changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is your friend: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog The first argument provided to you function will be the changed model:

```
someMethod: function(model, options){
  console.log("Model that changed: ", model);
  console.log("Options: ", options);
}
```